# Is API payload shown in a browser network tab a security risk?

Tags: security, browser, tabs, payload

We have public facing API service that is protected with JWT token over HTTPS. The issue of concern is that on the network tab of the browser, the payload for post request is in clear text. Can't a malicious user use this information to gain insight into the structure of our model or database?

I have search online for best practice in protecting API, but no information is raised in respect to clear payload in browser tab.